# Stuck reading first line of a file over and over

Tags: c++, getline, istringstream

I'm trying to record lines of data from a text file and store them in variables so I can use those variables to create and object with those values. My text file is set up to have a string1 num1 num2 string2. They are separated by white space and there's 15 lines. For now, I'm just trying to print them so I can easily tell it's working. However, it's printing the first line 15 times, so I'm guessing that it's just reading the first line and not proceeding to the next line. I'm just learning about reading from files though so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
ifstream inFile;
string line;
inFile.open("CellValues.txt");

//Check for Error
if (inFile.fail()) {
    cerr << "File does not exist!";
    exit(1);
}

int index = 0, max_num = 0;
string type, name;

istringstream inStream;
while (getline(inFile, line)) {
    inStream.str(line);

    inStream >> type >> index >> max_num >> name;

    cout << type << " / " << index << " of " << max_num << " / " << name << endl;

}
```

Comment: Please provide example input, and expected, and actual output.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `istringstream inStream` declaration inside the loop?

Comment: @flu I don't know why, but that did it. I didn't think i'd want to declare a new variable every iteration.

Comment: @sean, if you declare the `isStream` outside the loop, then you'll need to call `isStream.clear()` before `isStream.str(line)`.  Honestly, I don't know the full details behind this, but once you start streaming the contents of the stream are locked in and calling `str()` appears to just reset the cursor.  Calling `clear()` resets it.